# "Only input files can be specified as functions" in snakemake

Tags: snakemake

I am new to snakemake. I am trying this rule but have problems.

SOAPnuke takes in the forware read file and reverse read file as the input, filters reads and outputs files 'Clean_DP8400007518BR_L01_557_1.fq.gz' and 'Clean_DP8400007518BR_L01_557_2.fq.gz'.

```
SOAPnuke -1 DP8400007518BR_L01_557_1.fq.gz -2 DP8400007518BR_L01_557_1.fq.gz
```

Snakemake complains that "Only input files can be specified as functions" in the shell line.

Any suggestion to fix it? Thanks.

"config.yaml" is like this.

```
outdir: ./test
SOAPnuke: /path/to/SOAPnuke
filter:
    l: 10
    rate: 0.1
    m: 20
    n: 0.001
    Q: 2
    f: AAGTCGGAGGCCAAGCGGTCTTAGGAAGACAA
    r: AAGTCGGATCGTAGCCATGTCGTTCTGTGAGCCAAGGAGTTG
samples:
/path/to/A: sample_A
/path/to/B: sample_A
/path/to/C: sample_B
```

Under the paths, there are several fq.gz files belonging to the corresponding sample. The directory tree is like this.

```
|-- A
|   |-- DP8400007518BR_L01_557_1.fq.gz
|   |-- DP8400007518BR_L01_557_2.fq.gz
|   |-- DP8400007518BR_L01_558_1.fq.gz
|   |-- DP8400007518BR_L01_558_2.fq.gz
|   |-- DP8400007518BR_L01_559_1.fq.gz
|   |-- DP8400007518BR_L01_559_2.fq.gz
|   |-- DP8400007518BR_L01_560_1.fq.gz
|   `-- DP8400007518BR_L01_560_2.fq.gz
|-- A
|   |-- DP8400007587BR_L01_559_1.fq.gz
|   |-- DP8400007587BR_L01_559_2.fq.gz
|   |-- DP8400007587BR_L01_560_1.fq.gz
|   `-- DP8400007587BR_L01_560_2.fq.gz
`-- B
    |-- DP8400008089TR_L01_543_1.fq.gz
    |-- DP8400008089TR_L01_543_2.fq.gz
    |-- DP8400008089TR_L01_544_1.fq.gz
    `-- DP8400008089TR_L01_544_2.fq.gz
```

This is my snakefile

```
configfile: "config.yaml"

import os

outdir = os.path.abspath(config["outdir"])

def get_name(path):
    samples, = glob_wildcards(path+"/{id}_1.fq.gz")

rule filter:
    input:
        p1 = lambda wildcards: expand("{path}/{id}_1.fq.gz", path=config["samples"].keys(), id=get_name(path)),
        p2 = lambda wildcards: expand("{path}/{id}_2.fq.gz", path=config["samples"].keys(), id=get_name(path))

    output:
        f"{outdir}/{config['samples']}{{path}}/filter/Clean_{{id}}_1.fq.gz",
        f"{outdir}/{config['samples']}{{path}}/filter/Clean_{{id}}_2.fq.gz"

    params:
        SOAPnuke = config["SOAPnuke"],
        l = config["filter"]["l"],
        rate = config["filter"]["rate"],
        m = config["filter"]["m"],
        n = config["filter"]["n"],
        Q = config["filter"]["Q"],
        f = config["filter"]["f"],
        r = config["filter"]["r"]

    shell:
        """
        {params.SOAPnuke} filter -1 {input.p1} -2 {input.p2} -l {params.l} -q {params.q} -m {params.m} -n {params.n} -G -Q {params.Q} 
        -f {params.f} -r {params.r} -o f"{outdir}/{config['samples']}{{wildcards.path}}/filter/"
        """
```

The expected output is

```
|-- A
|   `-- filter
|       |-- Clean_DP8400007518BR_L01_557_1.fq.gz
|       |-- Clean_DP8400007518BR_L01_557_2.fq.gz
|       |-- Clean_DP8400007518BR_L01_558_1.fq.gz
|       |-- Clean_DP8400007518BR_L01_558_2.fq.gz
|       |-- Clean_DP8400007518BR_L01_559_1.fq.gz
|       |-- Clean_DP8400007518BR_L01_559_2.fq.gz
|       |-- Clean_DP8400007518BR_L01_560_1.fq.gz
|       |-- Clean_DP8400007518BR_L01_560_2.fq.gz
|       |-- Clean_DP8400007587BR_L01_559_1.fq.gz
|       |-- Clean_DP8400007587BR_L01_559_2.fq.gz
|       |-- Clean_DP8400007587BR_L01_560_1.fq.gz
|       `-- Clean_DP8400007587BR_L01_560_2.fq.gz
`-- B
    `-- filter
        |-- Clean_DP8400008089TR_L01_543_1.fq.gz
        |-- Clean_DP8400008089TR_L01_543_2.fq.gz
        |-- Clean_DP8400008089TR_L01_544_1.fq.gz
        `-- Clean_DP8400008089TR_L01_544_2.fq.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is something like this:

```
rule filter:
    input:
        p1 = lambda wildcards: expand("{path}/{id}_1.fq.gz", path=config["samples"].keys(), id=get_name(wildcards.path)),
        p2 = lambda wildcards: expand("{path}/{id}_2.fq.gz", path=config["samples"].keys(), id=get_name(wildcards.path))
    output:
        f"{outdir}/{config['samples']}{{path}}/filter/Clean_{{id}}_1.fq.gz",
        f"{outdir}/{config['samples']}{{path}}/filter/Clean_{{id}}_2.fq.gz"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it. Snakemake raised an error "name 'path' is not defined" in the first line of output block.

Comment: @ShangjinTan does it work now? I put them in double quotes

Comment: with using {{path}}, a new error occured, "No values given for wildcard 'outdir'." in this line. I guess this is because 'outdir' is predefined. So I put them in single quotes. Seems moving forward, but got an error, 'No values given for wildcard for /path/to/test/path/to/A'.    `expand(f"{outdir}/{config['samples']}{{path}}/filter/Clean_{{id}}_1.fq.gz"), expand(f"{outdir}/{config['samples']}{{path}}/filter/Clean_{{id}}_2.fq.gz")`

Comment: @ShangjinTan it's difficult for me to debug it without havind a minimal reproducible example. Can you try this? If it doesn't work; could you tell me what the result is of that when you print it?

Comment: the new error is "Target rules may not contain wildcards. Please specify concrete files or a rule without wildcards.".  I added how SOAPnuke works and the expected output to the body text. Hope this helps understanding.

Comment: @ShangjinTan, could you also specify what is the upstream rule calling rule filter?

Comment: This is the first rule. I realize that there is huge bug with this rule. The expand() function returns a list containing the files. However, SOAPnuke can only take a single file. So I will need to break it into multiple rules to work around. Thank you so much for following up.